# why is jest not required?

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

I have a react app and I don't know why I don't need to require the jest module.

```
import Task from './Task';

describe('class Task', () => {

  it('inProgress()', () => {
      var t = new Task("prova");
      expect(t.isInProgress()).not.toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` command for `create-react-app` runs `react-scripts test --env=jsdom`.

The script for `react-scripts test` requires `jest` [on this line](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/39c73ce5e36314cafa2c243e841600825c4a67ed/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L33) and after configuring everything it runs `jest` [on this line](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/39c73ce5e36314cafa2c243e841600825c4a67ed/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L115).

`jest` then finds your test files, loads them, and runs them.

In other words, *your tests don't load and run `jest`, it's `jest` that loads and runs your tests*.

Since your tests run within `jest` they can take advantage of the [globals](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api), [expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect), [environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string), etc. provided by `jest` without having to "require or import anything to use them".